# How to add text to a TextArea in java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, intellij-idea

I have this code:

```js
package com.butoane;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class App {
    private JButton apasaAiciButton;
    private JPanel Dunno;
    private JButton apoiaici;
    private JTextArea text1;

    public App() {
       String a = "H";
       String b = "e";
        apasaAiciButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                apoiaici.setEnabled(true);
                apasaAiciButton.setEnabled(false);
                text1.setText(toString(a));
            }

        });
        apoiaici.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                apoiaici.setEnabled(false);
                apasaAiciButton.setEnabled(true);
                apasaAiciButton.setText("Apasa iar aici");
                text1.setText(toString(b));
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("App");
        frame.setContentPane(new App().Dunno);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is, when one button is pressed, the text field gets either H or E, like : Button1(apasaAici) gets pressed, the text gets H
Button2(apoiAici) gets pressed, the text area gets an E after the "H", and, doing this over and over, the textarea to get every time an `HeHeHeHe`, you get it ?

How can I make this possible ?

Comment: How is this JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry , im new to java and stackoverflow , i didn't know pretty well what to put there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JTextArea.append(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append-java.lang.String-)

For your "H" button:

```
text1.append(a);
```

For your "e" button:

```
text1.append(b);
```